# Run time error while creating app server in Cloud formation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

I am currently learning how to build a cloud formation stack for a simple full stack application. So far I have come up with the following code

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

"Description" : "Trying to implement CICD for a simple full stack app",

"Parameters" : {

"AppInstanceType" : {
  "Description" : "App server EC2 instance type",
  "Type" : "String",
  "Default" : "t2.micro",
  "AllowedValues" : ["t2.micro"],
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
}
},

"Mappings" : {

"SecurityGroup" : {
  "publicALB": { "ID" : "sg-YYY" },
  "publicInstance": { "ID" : "sg-ZZZ" },
  "privateALB": { "ID" : "sg-AAA" },
  "privateInstance": { "ID" : "sg-BBB" }
},

"KeyName" : {
  "pem" : { "ID" : "SSSS" }
},

"VpcId" : {
  "VPC" : { "ID" : "vpc-GGG"  }
},

"Subnets" : {
  "public" : { "ID" : [ "subnet-MMM", "subnet-NNN" ] },
  "private" : { "ID" : [ "subnet-OOO", "subnet-III" ] }
},

"AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {
  "t2.micro" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  }
},

"AWSInstanceType2NATArch" : {
  "t2.micro" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  }
},

"AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
  "ap-south-1" : {"HVM64" : "ami-057752b3f1d6c4d6c", "HVMG2" : "ami-0475b505a31a28303"}
}

},

"Resources" : {

"AppServerGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { 
      "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
        "Subnets", 
        "public",
        "ID"
      ] 
    },
    "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
    "MinSize" : "1",
    "MaxSize" : "2",
    "TargetGroupARNs" : [ { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" } ]
  },
  "CreationPolicy" : {
    "ResourceSignal" : {
      "Timeout" : "PT15M",
      "Count"   : "1"
    }
  },
  "UpdatePolicy": {
    "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
      "MinInstancesInService": "1",
      "MaxBatchSize": "1",
      "PauseTime" : "PT15M",
      "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
    }
  }
},

"LaunchConfig" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Metadata" : {
    "Comment" : "Install a simple application",
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "config" : {
        "packages" : {
          "yum" : {
            "httpd" : []
          }
        },

        "files" : {
          
          "/var/www/html/index.html" : {
            "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["\n", [
              "<h1>Eureka BITCH</h1>"
            ]]},
            "mode"    : "000644",
            "owner"   : "root",
            "group"   : "root"
          },

          "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf" : {
            "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "[main]\n",
              "stack=", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, "\n",
              "region=", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
            ]]},
            "mode"    : "000400",
            "owner"   : "root",
            "group"   : "root"
          },

          "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf" : {
            "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
              "triggers=post.update\n",
              "path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
              "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
              "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
              "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
              "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
              "runas=root\n"
            ]]},
            "mode"    : "000400",
            "owner"   : "root",
            "group"   : "root"
          }
        },

        "services" : {
          "sysvinit" : {
            "httpd"    : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" },
            "cfn-hup" : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true",
                          "files" : ["/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf", "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Properties" : {
    "KeyName" : { 
      "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
        "KeyName", 
        "pem",
        "ID" 
      ] 
    },
    "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
      "AWSRegionArch2AMI", 
      { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
      { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "AppInstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } 
    ] },
    "SecurityGroups" : [
      { 
        "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
          "SecurityGroup", 
          "publicInstance",
          "ID" 
        ] 
      }
    ],
    "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "AppInstanceType" },
    "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
         "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
         "sudo yum update -y",
         "sudo yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

         "suod yum update -y aws-cli\n",

         "sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
         "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
         "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
         "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

         "sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
         "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
         "         --resource AppServerGroup ",
         "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
         "sudo yum install -y httpd",                             ---- LINE X
         "sudo systemctl start httpd.service",
         "sudo systemctl enable httpd.service",
         "echo \"<h1>Eureka BITCH UserData</h1>\""                ---- LINE Y
    ]]}}
  }
},

"AppServerScaleUpPolicy" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
  "Properties" : {
    "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
    "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "AppServerGroup" },
    "Cooldown" : "60",
    "ScalingAdjustment" : "1"
  }
},
"AppServerScaleDownPolicy" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
  "Properties" : {
    "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
    "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "AppServerGroup" },
    "Cooldown" : "60",
    "ScalingAdjustment" : "-1"
  }
},

"CPUAlarmHigh": {
 "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
 "Properties": {
    "AlarmDescription": "Scale-up if CPU > 90% for 10 minutes",
    "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
    "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
    "Statistic": "Average",
    "Period": "300",
    "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
    "Threshold": "90",
    "AlarmActions": [ { "Ref": "AppServerScaleUpPolicy" } ],
    "Dimensions": [
      {
        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
        "Value": { "Ref": "AppServerGroup" }
      }
    ],
    "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
  }
},
"CPUAlarmLow": {
 "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
 "Properties": {
    "AlarmDescription": "Scale-down if CPU < 70% for 10 minutes",
    "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
    "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
    "Statistic": "Average",
    "Period": "300",
    "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
    "Threshold": "70",
    "AlarmActions": [ { "Ref": "AppServerScaleDownPolicy" } ],
    "Dimensions": [
      {
        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
        "Value": { "Ref": "AppServerGroup" }
      }
    ],
    "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
  }
},

"ApplicationLoadBalancer" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties" : {
    "Subnets" : { 
      "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
        "Subnets", 
        "public",
        "ID" 
      ] 
    },
    "SecurityGroups" : [
      { 
        "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
          "SecurityGroup", 
          "publicALB",
          "ID" 
        ] 
      }
    ]
  }
},

"ALBListener" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
  "Properties" : {
    "DefaultActions" : [{
      "Type" : "forward",
      "TargetGroupArn" : { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" }
    }],
    "LoadBalancerArn" : { "Ref" : "ApplicationLoadBalancer" },
    "Port" : "80",
    "Protocol" : "HTTP"
  }
},

"ALBTargetGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds" : 30,
    "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds" : 5,
    "HealthyThresholdCount" : 3,
    "Port" : 80,
    "Protocol" : "HTTP",
    "UnhealthyThresholdCount" : 5,
    "VpcId" : { 
      "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
        "VpcId", 
        "VPC",
        "ID" 
      ] 
    }
  }
}
},

"Outputs" : {
"URL" : {
  "Description" : "The URL of the website",
  "Value" :  { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [
      "ApplicationLoadBalancer", "DNSName" ]}]]}
}
}
}
```

The stack is "compiled" successfully and the parameter for the instance is selected and the "execution" of the stack begins. In the resources tab it says that ALBListener, ALBTargetGroup, ApplicationLoadBalancer, and LaunchConfig are created successfully, but AppServerGroup is given as create in progress. It stays like that for a long time. The longest I've waited is like 2 hrs. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Relavent Info:

> The SG and the Subnets mentioned in the AppServerGroup are configured fine. I deployed an instance manually and I was able to run yum update and ping in that machine.

> The Instance is created from the stack but httpd is not installed in it.

> I read somewhere that launchConfig was retired and we need to use launchTemplate. If that is the case can someone tell me how to fix the above code

> The ALB is reachable from the public internet and gives 502 error

> I tried to run the code without LINE X TO LINE Y in the code. Same issue

> The SG for the instance has outbound rules to (HTTP, HTTPS) public ALB SG and (HTTPS) internet, and inbound rules from (HTTP, HTTPS) public ALB SG

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

I updated launch config to launch template as follows and that fixed the issue

```
"LaunchConfig": {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate",
  "Properties" : {
      "LaunchTemplateData" : {
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
          "AWSRegionArch2AMI", 
          { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
          { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "AppInstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } 
        ] },
        "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "AppInstanceType" },
        "KeyName" : { 
          "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
            "KeyName", 
            "pem",
            "ID" 
          ] 
        },
        "SecurityGroupIds" : [
          { 
            "Fn::FindInMap" : [ 
              "SecurityGroup", 
              "publicInstance",
              "ID" 
            ] 
          }
        ],
        "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
          "yum update -y\n",
          "sudo yum install -y httpd\n",
          "sudo systemctl start httpd.service\n",
          "sudo systemctl enable httpd.service\n",
          "echo \"<h1>Eureka BITCH UserData</h1>\" > /var/www/html/index.html"
        ]]}}
      },
      "LaunchTemplateName" : { "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-launch-template" }
    }
},
```